# Error al utilizar exec() en PHP para copiar desde Centos a Windows

Tags: php, apache, centos

En Windows tengo una carpeta compartida que la monté como `/mnt/winfile/` en Centos 7. A ésta puedo acceder desde Centos linux para copiar archivos. Todo funciona bien si copio desde la consola.

Creé el archivo `file_copy.php` y cuando lo ejecuto como `php -q file_copy.php` desde la consola copia bien los archivos.

El problema es que si trato de llamar desde la web por ejemplo `http://192.168.1.15/file_copy.php` entrega el error:

> cp: cannot create regular file '/mnt/winfile/archivoprueba.log': Permission denied

Tengo entendido que es debido a que por consola se copia con un usuario con permisos y desde apache o la web utiliza un usuario sin privilegios. Si es así ¿cómo doy los privilegios para que funcione desde la web de idéntica forma como desde la consola?.

El archivo PHP `file_copy.php` es simple solo tiene el comando para copiar a través de `exec()`:

```
<?php
$copia="cp archivoprueba.log /mnt/winfile/archivoprueba.log";
exec($copia);
?>
```

Comment: Deduzco que las pruebas en consola las hiciste usando el usuario `root` (mala costumbre). Tienes varias opciones para hacer lo que deseas. La mejor es que montes el recurso cifs con el usuario `www-data` o el usuario que use tu apache usando las opciones de montaje `uid=33,gid=33`, así podrá escribir en el recurso compartido sin problemas. La peor opción es montar con las opciones `file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777`, que otorga permisos de escritura a todos los usuarios del sistema (he usado `0666` en `file_mode` para evitar que se pueda ejecutar un script alojado en el recurso compartido windows).

Comment: ¿Has probado algo de lo que te comenté anteriormente?

Comment: Hola Oscar, finalmente tuve que generar unos permisos en la carpeta, gracias por tú tiempo.

Comment: Publica como respuesta la forma en la que lo solucionaste para que pueda ayudar a otros con el mismo problema y yo mismo te doy el primer +1.